# How do I return a row with 0 if the group by has 0 records?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have this ***alert_levels*** table:

```
| id |  levels  |
-----------------
| 1  | critical |
| 2  |   error  |
| 3  |  warning |
| 4  |   info   |
```

Then I have this **alerts** table

```
| id |       alert_time        | alert_level_id | alert_type |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 2020-03-01 08:01:00.000 |        4       |    Type 1  |
| 2  | 2020-03-03 10:58:00.000 |        4       |    Type 1  |
| 3  | 2020-03-17 09:05:00.000 |        4       |    Type 2  |
| 4  | 2020-03-21 21:03:00.000 |        4       |    Type 2  |
| 5  | 2020-03-27 23:10:00.000 |        4       |    Type 1  |
| 6  | 2020-04-10 05:49:00.000 |        4       |    Type 2  |
| 7  | 2020-04-10 06:29:00.000 |        4       |    Type 2  |
| 8  | 2020-04-14 18:56:00.000 |        4       |    Type 2  |
| 9  | 2020-04-19 22:34:00.000 |        4       |    Type 2  |
...
```

The ***alert_level_id*** in the alerts table is a foreign key of ***id*** from the alert_levels table.

What I want is to count the number of occurences of each alert_type grouped by the alert_level_id whithin a chosen time period. And if there is no occurency then it should show 0.

This is how it should look like:

```
| alert_level_id | type_1_count | type_2_count | total_count|
-------------------------------------------------------------
|        1       |       0      |       0      |      0     |
|        2       |       0      |       0      |      0     |
|        3       |       0      |       0      |      0     |
|        4       |       9      |      130     |     139    |
```

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT al.id, 
       count(CASE WHEN alert_type = 'Type 1' THEN 1 END) type_1_count, 
       count(CASE WHEN log_type = 'Type 2' THEN 1 END) type_2_count, 
       count(CASE WHEN log_type = 'Type 1' OR log_type = 'Type 2' THEN 1 END) total_count
FROM alert_levels al
LEFT JOIN alerts a ON al.id = a.alert_level_id
WHERE a.alert_time >= ? AND a.alert_time < ?
GROUP BY al.id
ORDER BY al.id ASC;
```

The first thing with this query is that I feel like there is a simpler query for this, and secondly if there is only alerts with a an alert_level_id 4 in the chosen period, it only retuns one the row with that alert level. But I always want all 4 rows returned..

Comment: I guess you can try to replace your count with SUM(CASE WHEN alert_type = 'Type 1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) type_1_count

Comment: @Sergey I just tried it, it still only returns one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use `filter` for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT al.id, 
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE a.alert_type = 'Type 1') as type_1_count, 
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE a.alter_type = 'Type 2') as type_2_count, 
       COUNT(a.id) as total_count
FROM alert_levels al LEFT JOIN
     alerts a
     ON al.id = a.alert_level_id AND
        a.alert_time >= ? AND a.alert_time < ? AND
        a.type in ('Type 1', 'Type 2')
GROUP BY al.id
ORDER BY al.id ASC;
```

Also note the conditions that have been moved to the `ON` clause.